# Incorporate LiveStream in Android app

Tags: android, video, streaming

Is there a way in incorporate a LiveStream (from http://www.livestream.com) in an Android app?

It seems that its possible to extract a m3u8 file, perhaps this is a viable route to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RTSP stream provided by livestream, and open it with the intent action VIEW, which will open the stream with the default player.

To get the appropriate RTSP url, you should send a request to the custom url :

```
"http://x" + yourChannel + "x.channel-api.livestream-api.com/2.0/getstream"
```

This will return a XML data, you can check its structure in this test channel url http://xlivestreamapi43x.channel-api.livestream-api.com/2.0/getstream , then you will have the desired RTSP url in the field androidURL.